# Finding the formula for the sequence: 7, 10, 16, 25, etc, in terms of $n$, given...

Tags: sequences-and-series

> In terms of $n$, find the formula for the sequence $a_n$: 7, 10, 16, 25; given that the difference between each adjacent element in the sequence creates an arithmetic sequence of its own.

I got the incorrect solution and I cannot trace my mistake:

We create a new sequence $b_n$ based on the given information:

$b_1 = 10 - 7 = 3$
$b_2 = 16 - 10 = 6$
$b_3 = 25-16 = 9$
$d_{b_n} = 3$

We know that:
$$a_n - a_{n-1} = b_{n-1}$$
If we were to add all possible elements:
$$A_n - A_{n-1} = B_{n-1}$$
We also know that $A_n - A_{n-1} = a_n$, so therefore $a_n = B_{n-1}$:
$$a_n = \frac{[2b_1 + d(n-2)](n-1)}{2} = \boxed{\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}}$$
However, this is incorrect as it gives values inconsistent with the definition of the sequence.
The correct answer is $\frac{3n^2-3n+14}{2}$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you used the initial condition $a_1=7$.  Just knowing the differences between terms in a sequence does not determine the sequence uniquely.  You still need some more information, like a starting value.

Comment: @lulu Isn't it implied from $b_1 = 10 - 7 = 3$?

Comment: No.  Just knowing that $a_2-a_1=3$ doesn't tell you what $a_1,a_2$ are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error when adding the sequences up to $n$.

You have the following:

$$
a_2 - a_1 = b_1 \\
a_3 - a_2 = b_2 \\
\dots \\
a_n - a_{n - 1} = b_{n - 1}
$$

So, when you add these equalities, you get:

$$\sum_2^n a_i + \sum_1^{n-1}a_i = \sum_1^{n-1}b_i$$

The second term here is indeed $A_{n-1}$, and the right hand side is $B_{n=1}$, but the first is $A_n - a_1$. Therefore you have $A_n - a_1 - A_{n-1} = B_{n-1}$. Now, using $A_n - A_{n-1} = a_n$, we have
$$a_n = B_{n-1} + a_1 = \frac{3n(n-1)}{2} + 7$$